# adding new item to state react

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a little react redux project where have some player list in redux I can delete that and update that.. but adding new is not working ..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Hockey! exercise 9.2</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/redux@latest/dist/redux.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/babel">
        const { createStore, combineReducers } = Redux;
        const initialState = [];


        /* Reducer Function to add, delete and Update all the Player */
        function myReducer(state = initialState, action){
            if(action.type === 'ADD PLAYER' ){
                    state.push(action.val)
            }
            if(action.type === 'UPDATE PLAYER' ){
                    for (var i = 0; i < state.length; i++) {
                    if (state[i].id === action.val.id) {
                        state[i].activeStatus = action.val.activeStatus;
                        console.log("Player Updated");
                    }
                }
                return state;
            }
            if(action.type === 'DELETE PLAYER' ){
                console.log(action.val.id);
                return state.filter(player => (player.id !== action.val.id));
                console.log("Player Deleted");
            }   
            return state;
        }

        /* Function to implement the player edit and delete*/
        function playerDetails(player){
            for(var i in player) {
                        var container = document.getElementById('allPlayers');
                        var btn = document.createElement('button');
                        btn.textContent = player[i].name;
                        btn.id = player[i].id
                        container.appendChild(btn);
                        btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
                            for(var j in player){
                                if(this.id == player[j].id){
                                var content =  document.createElement('div');
                                var editButton = document.createElement('button');
                                var deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
                                editButton.textContent= "Change Status"
                                deleteButton.textContent= "Delete Player"
                                content.textContent = `Name: ${player[j].name}, is active: ${player[j].activeStatus}`;
                                container.appendChild(content);
                                if (player[j].activeStatus===true){
                                    container.appendChild(editButton);
                                }
                                container.appendChild(deleteButton);
                                editButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
                                    if (player[j].activeStatus===true){
                                        store.dispatch({type: 'UPDATE PLAYER', val: {id : player[j].id, activeStatus: false}}) 
                                        content.textContent = `Name: ${player[j].name}, is active: ${player[j].activeStatus}`;
                                        console.log(store.getState());
                                    }
                                })
                                deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
                                    store.dispatch({type: 'DELETE PLAYER', val: {id: player[j].id}});
                                    console.log(store.getState());
                                    var newplayer = store.getState().myReducer
                                    playerDetails(newplayer);
                                })
                                break;                                       
                             }
                            }
                            });


                        }

        }

        function add(){

        }



        /* Reducer Function to Get all the Player */

        function getPlayer(state = {}, action){
            if(action.type === 'GET PLAYER' ){
                const player= action.playerData;
                playerDetails(player);
            }
            return state;
        }

        const rootReducer = combineReducers({
                myReducer,
                getPlayer
            })
        const store = createStore(rootReducer)

        const player1 = {
            id: 1,
            name : "Towfiq Omi",
            activeStatus: true
        }
        const player2 = {
            id: 2,
            name : "Jesse Lingard",
            activeStatus: true
        }
        const player3 = {
            id: 3,
            name : "Mercus Rashford",
            activeStatus: true
        }
        const player4 = {
            id: 4,
            name : "Anthony Martial",
            activeStatus: true
        }
        store.dispatch({type: 'ADD PLAYER', val: player1});
        store.dispatch({type: 'ADD PLAYER', val: player2});
        store.dispatch({type: 'ADD PLAYER', val: player3});
        store.dispatch({type: 'ADD PLAYER', val: player4});
        store.dispatch({type: 'GET PLAYER', playerData : store.getState().myReducer});
        console.log(store.getState());
    </script>
    <p>Hockey players</p>
    <div id="allPlayers"></div>
    <br>
    <div id="player"></div>
    <div id="newplayer"></div>
    <br>
    <form id="addPlayerForm">
        Name: <input type="text" id="player" name="name">
        <br> Active: <input type="checkbox" name="active">
    </form>
    <button id="add" type="button" value="Add" onclick="add();">Add a player</button>
</body>
</html>
```

In the add function I want to add new data.. I have tryed to get the value by js document.get element by id but it is not working 
I am new to react and redux. someone help me..
Thanks in advance...

Comment: You want to add new data in state?

Comment: yes i want to add new item

Comment: In the react,redux world if you want to update the state, you dispatch a relevant action. Code against action is defined in the reducer function, that code is responsible for updating the state.

I don't know which source you are following but I think you need to revise the code you currently have.

Comment: i need to add new item and show all item after all adding

Comment: Where communication with state is required you must dispatch an action.

Comment: can you please do what ever you need to add new item and give a small brief @ZainUlAbideen

Comment: example is shared

Answer (score 3):

```
function add(){
  dispatch({"type: "ADD_NEW_DATA"})
}
```

In reducer function:

```
if (action.type === "ADD_NEW_DATA") {
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
    todos: [
      ...state.yourStateWhereYouWantToAddItem,
      {
        data
      }
    ]
  })
}
```

Comment: can you please add that on my project pls

Comment: It will be great if you'd add it by yourself

Comment: dispath is not a function

Comment: You have to import dispatch from redux first

Answer (score 2):

The redux state always needs to be immutable, thats one of the core principles of use redux.

Within your `myReducer` function, change your code as shown below

```js
if(action.type === 'ADD PLAYER' ){
  return [...state, action.val]
}
```

PS: Also you need to change rest of the reducers to make them immutable.

Comment: can you please add the on my html